# How to add Text in a specific cells by VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to put in my sheets on the cell :

```
"I7" the word "Bronze"
"I8" the word "Silver"
"I9" the word "Gold"
"I10" the word "Platin"
```

Because on the on the Cells "J7" I have a formula for the total of Bronze.
which is this one :

```
Sheets("Download").Select
Cells.Select
Range("J7").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "= COUNTIF(C:C,""Bronze"")"

  Sheets("Download").Select
Cells.Select
Range("J8").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "= COUNTIF(C:C,""Silver"")"

  Sheets("Download").Select
Cells.Select
Range("J9").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "= COUNTIF(C:C,""Gold"")"

  Sheets("Download").Select
Cells.Select
Range("J10").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "= COUNTIF(C:C,""Platin"")"

  Sheets("Download").Select
Cells.Select
Range("J11").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "= COUNTIF(C:C,""PlPlus"")"

  Sheets("Download").Select
Cells.Select
Range("J12").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "= COUNTIF(C:C,""Ambass"")"

  Sheets("Download").Select
Cells.Select
Range("J13").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "= SUM(J7:J12)"
```

It gaves me number but to make it easy I want to see what's the total of Bronze, silver etc...

Comment: Why not put a pivot table in I7 and avoid VBA altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub TEST()
Const kFml As String = "=COUNTIF(C[-7],RC9)"    'Use a constant to define the formula
Dim aValues As Variant
aValues = [{"Bronze","Silver","Gold","Platin","PlPlus","Ambass"}]   'Use an array to contain all the values

    With Sheets("Download").Range("I7:I12")                         'Work with the target range
        .Columns(1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aValues)    'Applies the values to 1st column `I`
        .Columns(2).FormulaR1C1 = kFml                              'Applies the formula to 2nd column `J`
    End With
    Sheets("Download").Range("J13").Formula = "= SUM(J7:J12)"       'Enters total formula
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Dim arr, i

arr = Array("Bronze","Silver","Gold","Platin")'<< add the rest here...

For i = lbound(arr) to UBound(arr)
    With Sheets("Download").Range("I7")
       .Offset(i, 0).Value = arr(i)
       .Offset(i, 1).Formula = "= COUNTIF(C:C,""" & arr(i) & """)"
    End With
Next i
```